# react public folder images suddenly dont work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, create-react-app

I have many images and audios in my react project using create-react-app and thus Im using the public folder to use the images in my components. Yesterday night all the images where displayed correctly, and even displayed in github pages worked. But it just stopped working locally today. Ive tried updating packages, checking out in git to see if the problem were not there in previous commits, but none of that worked. Idk if it has something to do with npm packages or if you have encountered this problem before. Thank yoou

I just pushed to github the code and the images look good

[image]

and with the same code in localhost

[image]

The images are downloaded properly in localhost but it says type text/html instead of the extension of the image

[image]

Edit

It turns that the homepage attribute of the package.json changed the path of the localhost, although it rendered without that path, ant thus all the previous paths got messed up, use process.env.PUBLIC_URL to prevent this type of errors if using public folder

Comment: Something has changed. Code doesn't just stop working if you don't change anything, particularly if it's hosted locally. We'd probably need to see the repo, or a [mcve] to be able to debug this if you can't.

Comment: @Andy may the images uploaded give more context and thanks for your help,